# How to update the serial numbers of a set of records at once

Tags: java, sql, algorithm

Suppose the original records have 5 records, in the following order

```sql
| name | seq |
|  A   |  1  |
|  B   |  2  |
|  C   |  3  |
|  D   |  4  |
|  E   |  5  |
```

I need to re-update the seq of these 5 records to the following status at once

```sql
| name | seq |
|  A   |  2  |
|  B   |  3  |
|  C   |  1  |
|  D   |  5  |
|  E   |  4  |
```

An update means a batch of update operations that commit updates to only one record each time, rather than updating other records in turn

If the above data needs to be modified, 7 update operations are submitted at a time:

```sql
A (seq: 1 -> 0)
C (seq: 3 -> 1)
B (seq: 2 -> 3)
A (seq: 0 -> 2)
D (seq: 4 -> 0)
E (seq: 5 -> 4)
D (seq: 0 -> 5)
```

How do I use Java or sql processing to finally achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

sql CASE..WHEN

for example:

```
UPDATE tablename SET seq = (
    CASE name 
    WHEN 'A' THEN 2 
    WHEN 'B' THEN 3  
    WHEN 'C' THEN 1  
    WHEN 'D' THEN 5  
    WHEN 'E' THEN 4  
    END)
WHERE name in('A','B', 'C','D','E');
```

Comment: I don't involve `name` in my requirements, which means use only the `seq` column to do the operation